# Integration of Flyway into JPA + OSGi

Tags: jpa, osgi, eclipselink, flyway, jpa-2.2

in my current project I have integrated JPA into OSGi standalone application. For integration I have taken following OSGi specification Implementations:

- OSGi R7 Platform (Equinox 3.13.0)
- JPA 2.2 (Eclipselink 2.7.1)
- JPA Container

  - Apache Aries JPA Container 2.7.0
  - Apache Aries JPA Eclipselink adapter 2.7.0
- JDBC Service (PAX JDBC MariaDB 1.3.0)

This integration works perfect.

The next step to go - Flyway integration. The DB Migration Scripts should be packed directly into Persistence Bundle. Now I would like to trigger the migration exactly when DataSource is created, immediately before EntityManagerFactory and EntityManagerFactoryBuilder Services will be Registerd. At this moment I should have access to Persistence Bundle class loader and i should have an initialized Datasource. The only solution, that I have found, is to refactor Apache Areas JPA Container and put a Flyway migration call into AriesEntityManagerFactoryBuilder.dataSourceReady. The Flyway trigger is stored as locations in JPA properties like this:

```
    <property name="org.flywaydb.Locations" value="classpath:com/hrrm/budget/domain/account/migrations"/>
```

This solution is correct placed at a perfect time to call. But it is not confirm with OSGi JPA Service Specification 1.1 and was implemented as a hook into Apache Aries JPA Container.

Is there another more perfect and specification-confirm solution to integrate Flyway into my project?

Answer (score 0):

To hook into the DataSource creation you can use a PreHook service like described in the [pax-jdbc docs](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/spaces/PAXJDBC/pages/61767710/Create+DataSource+from+config).

You can find an [example here](https://github.com/cschneider/Karaf-Tutorial/blob/master/liquibase/service/src/main/java/net/lr/tutorial/db/service/Migrator.java).

```
@Component(property="name=persondb")
public class Migrator implements PreHook {
    public void prepare(DataSource ds) throws SQLException {
        // Put your migration calls here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have already checked this solution and it seems good but I have no idea to which persistence unit belongs this datasource. This info is important for me to find out, which migration should start.But thanks a lot

Comment: You can define a name for the hook and refer to it in the DS definition. So this way you link a certain hook impl to a certain DS.